# ajax, Show modal if yes then continue with another ajax if not continue with the loop

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I've been trying for a day to know how to solve this, I really tried to search an answer but i guess i couldn't or i didn't understand.

Here are the steps from my problem:

1.- I will do a for , so i have to process each record one by one using ajax (i saw that using async :false  will let me process one by one and not all at the same time, i mean it is like a fifo, am i right? cause i need that,because i'm using httpsession some vars need to be changed one by one, thats why i'm trying to process each record one by one, although in my example  i don't show this)

2.- if my validation is 1 i will call next ajax but if it is number 2 i have to ask the user to put somethig and then continue with another ajax and then this ajax will call the other ajax as number 1 (here is one of my problem because when i show the modal, the modal is displayed but it continues in the loop so i need to stop my ajax untill the user put something and when he clicks "Save changes" it must continue with the loop, although as i said this is not happening (i tried to use a while(true) but i didn't had a chance my browser stops the script), my program shows the modal and continue looping no matter what)

3.-If user see the modal and click close, well i won't continue with my ajax but i will continue with my loop or my for, because i need to process all things.

This is an example of the modal:

[image]

And now, as you can see, yeah my modal showed up but my loop continue no matter what :(

[image]

So as i said i need this:

1.- i'm doing a for in order to process all my stuff, but depending of the answer sometimes i have to show the modal, so when user click in savechanges it will call another ajax and then another ajax and continue the loop, but if user click in close well i have to stop the next ajax calls and continue with my for in the next position and do it again again and again untill my for stops.

2.-in other words i have to call my ajax number 1,2,4 if my result is 1 in ajax number 2, but if my result in ajax number 2 is == 2 then i have to show modal and stop the for because it continues looping, and depending of the answe if it is save changes then i have to call ajax3 and this will call ajax4 but if it is close then i have to continue in the next loop, and again, this could happen depending of the answer.

Here are my examples code:

JSP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  var positionNumber = 1;
  $(".clickme").click(function(){
    for(var i=0; i < 10; i++){
        ajaxOne();
    }

    $("body").on('click', '.btn-default', function(e) {
      console.log('ok we finish no more calls to servlets');
      $('#myModal').modal('hide')   ;
      console.log('BUT LETS CONTINUE WITH THE FOR.... WE HAVE TO CHECK ALL THE ITEMS')
    });

    $("body").on('click', '.btn-primary', function(e) {
      console.log('ok lets call now ajax three');
      ajaxThree();
    });
  });



  function ajaxOne(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Test/one",
      //contentType : "text/xml",
      async :false ,
      beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('CALLING POSITION: '+positionNumber);
        console.log('Call Servlet one')
      },
      success: function(data,status,xhr){
        console.log(data)
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
      },
      complete: function(){
        positionNumber++;
        console.log('finish Call Servlet one')
        ajaxTwo();
      }
     });
  }


  function ajaxTwo(){
    var text;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Test/two",
      //contentType : "text/xml",
      async :false ,
      beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('Call Servlet two')
      },
      success: function(data,status,xhr){
      console.log(data);
      text = data;
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('finish Call Servlet two')
        if(parseInt(text)==2){
          $('#myModal').modal('show')   ; // I have to show the modal, and stop all processing,
                                          // if he select save changes I will call ajax 3 and then four, if he select cancel then
                                          // I have to continue with my loop again...
                                          // Here I need a little help :'( thank you so much
        }else{
          ajaxFour();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  function ajaxThree(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Test/three",
      //contentType : "text/xml",
      async :false ,
      beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('Call Servlet three')
      },
      success: function(data,status,xhr){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('finish Call Servlet three')
        ajaxFour();
      }
    });
  }

  function ajaxFour(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/Test/four",
      //contentType : "text/xml",
      async :false ,
        beforeSend: function () {
        console.log('Call Servlet four')
      },
      success: function(data,status,xhr){
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
        alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
      },
      complete: function(){
        console.log('finish Call Servlet four')
      }
    });
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="clickme">click me </div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Servlet one

```
package com.dot.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServeletOne
 */
@WebServlet(name = "one", urlPatterns = { "/one" })
public class ServeletOne extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServeletOne() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Yep i did a post");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     out.println("one");
  }

}
```

Servlet two

```
package com.dot.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServeletOne
 */
@WebServlet(name = "two", urlPatterns = { "/two" })
public class ServeletOne2 extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServeletOne2() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Yep i did a post");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int tmp = (int) ( Math.random() * 2 + 1);
    System.out.println(tmp);
     out.println(tmp);
  }

}
```

Servlet three

```
package com.dot.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServeletOne
 */
@WebServlet(name = "three", urlPatterns = { "/three" })
public class ServeletOne3 extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServeletOne3() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Yep i did a post");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     out.println("three");
  }

}
```

servlet four

```
package com.dot.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ServeletOne
 */
@WebServlet(name = "four", urlPatterns = { "/four" })
public class ServeletOne4 extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ServeletOne4() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
  }

  /**
   * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   */
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Yep i did a post");
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     out.println("four");
  }

}
```

Comment: *"i saw that using async :false"* - Don't use `async: false`. Structure your code in such a way that it can work with `async: true`. (E.g., start the next Ajax from the `complete` callback of the previous, like how you currently do with some of your calls.) Also, having one button click trigger up to 40 Ajax calls seems a bit excessive. Isn't there some way to consolidate some of those calls?

Comment: if i use true it will call all the ajax as soon as possible, i mean i could get an error because i'm using http session, so if i have to change to true, i don't have to use httpsession i have to use request session, that would be better in that case, but as i'm not using request session, i can't do that :( but I changed it as you said and nevermind my problem still the same :( my modal show up and do not stop the ajax, but thank you =D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that changing to `async: false` would solve the problem. I said to structure your code in such a way that it can work with `async: true`, in other words, rewrite things to work properly asynchronously, because synchronous ajax is horrible from the user's point of view. If you need to open a modal dialog then trigger the next ajax operation after the modal is closed (presumably the modal has some kind of callback function to tell you when the user closes it).

Comment: yeah i've readen that a call back could help but to be honest, i didn't know how to use it or what , if i try to change the code in order to work with async true, i think i have to make a lot of changes, because im using java, so i have to send the request , expect the response, and again, i don't want that because it would be a pain in the ass i guess, but thank you, i didn't think in that, glad to read it

Comment: nnnnnnnnnnnnn ty so much, i have to use async false, and i also solved it =) but thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my error I used some flags

```
var positionNumber = 0;
    var flagPressedButton = false;
```

and in my for i used other way

```
for(i; i < 10;){

            ajaxOne();
                 i++;
                 if(continuar == false) break;
```

and when my modal shows up if everything is ok i simulate a click again

$(".clickme").click();

Here is all my js code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var continuar = true;
    var positionNumber = 0;
    var flagPressedButton = false;
    var i=0;
    $(".clickme").click(function(event){

        for(i; i < 10;){

            ajaxOne();
                 i++;
                 if(continuar == false) break;

        }


      $("body").on('click', '.btn-default', function(e) {
          console.log('ok we finish no more calls to servlets');
          $('#myModal').modal('hide')   ;
          console.log('BUT LETS CONTINUE WITH THE FOR.... WE HAVE TO CHECK ALL THE ITEMS')
        $(".clickme").click();
      });

      $("body").on('click', '.btn-primary', function(e) {
          console.log('ok lets call now ajax three');
          ajaxThree();
        $(".clickme").click();
      });

    });



function ajaxOne(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
             url: "/Test/one",
           //contentType : "text/xml",

           async :false ,
           beforeSend: function () {
               continuar =true;
                 positionNumber++;
               console.log('CALLING POSITION: '+positionNumber);
             console.log('Call Servlet one')
                },
             success: function(data,status,xhr){
                console.log('complete: ', JSON.parse(data));
                var statusCode = JSON.parse(data).responseCode;
                console.log('satusCode: ', statusCode);
                if (statusCode) {
                    ajaxTwo(statusCode);
                }
                                      },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){
                  alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
                         }

           });

}


    function ajaxTwo(){
        var text;
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                 url: "/Test/two",
               //contentType : "text/xml",
               async :false ,
               beforeSend: function () {
                 console.log('Call Servlet two')
                    },
                 success: function(data,status,xhr){
                    console.log(data);
                    text = data;

                                          },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                      alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
                             },
                         complete: function(){
                             console.log('finish Call Servlet two')

                            if(parseInt(text)==2){
                                console.error('LLAMARE A LA MODAL');
                                   $('#myModal').modal('show')   ;
                                   continuar = false;
                            }else{
                                ajaxFour();
                            }
                            }

               });

    }

    function ajaxThree(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                 url: "/Test/three",
               //contentType : "text/xml",
               async :false ,
               beforeSend: function () {
                 console.log('Call Servlet three')
                    },
                 success: function(data,status,xhr){
                    console.log(data);

                                          },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                      alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
                             },
                         complete: function(){
                             console.log('finish Call Servlet three')
                                                            console.error('CERRARE A LA MODALA Y CONTINUARE');
                             $('#myModal').modal('hide')   ;
                             ajaxFour();
                             continuar = true;
                            }

               });

    }

    function ajaxFour(){
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
                 url: "/Test/four",
               //contentType : "text/xml",
               async :false ,
               beforeSend: function () {
                 console.log('Call Servlet four')
                    },
                 success: function(data,status,xhr){
                    console.log(data);

                                          },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error){
                      alert("Error!" + xhr.status);
                             },
                         complete: function(){
                             console.log('finish Call Servlet four')
                            }

               });

    }
});
</script>
```

As i Said, i neded to show a modal and then continue, well i solve it in this way and now it's working fine for me =) and do not forget use async :false , in order to make a petition by petition

[image]
[image]

[image]